# How to add a UI element above Map Icon to show address in Windows 10?

Tags: c#, windows-10-universal

I am working on MapControl in Windows 10 and I want to display Location Address above map icon. I know how to add a map icon but not aware of adding a UI element above it. I added Map Icon using following code

```
MapControl map = frameworkElement as MapControl;
map.MapServiceToken= "my service token";
BasicGeoposition councilPosition = new BasicGeoposition()
{
     Latitude = Convert.ToDouble(Info.GetType().GetRuntimeProperty("LATITUDE").GetValue(Info, null)),
     Longitude = Convert.ToDouble(Info.GetType().GetRuntimeProperty("LONGITUDE").GetValue(Info, null))
};

Geopoint pinPoint = new Geopoint(councilPosition);

MapIcon locationPin = new MapIcon();
locationPin.Image= RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(new Uri("ms-appx:///Images/pushpin.png"));
locationPin.Title = councilInfo.COUNCIL_NAME;
locationPin.CollisionBehaviorDesired = MapElementCollisionBehavior.RemainVisible;
locationPin.Location = councilPoint;
locationPin.NormalizedAnchorPoint = new Point(0.5, 1.0);
locationPin.ZIndex = 0;

map.MapElements.Add(locationPin);
await map.TrySetViewAsync(locationPin.Location, 15D, 0, 0, MapAnimationKind.Bow);
```

and I want to achieve same as below screenshots

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since programmatic adding MapIcons is hectic for custom template. Here's how I am using map Control inside my app

```
    <maps:MapControl x:Name="MapControl"  MapServiceToken="YourToken" >
                    <maps:MapItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding YourData, Mode=TwoWay}">
                        <maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Tapped="MapIcon_Tapped" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Image Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" maps:MapControl.Location="{Binding Location}" maps:MapControl.NormalizedAnchorPoint="0.5,0.5" Source="ms-appx:///Images/pushpin.png"/>
                                    <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="LightGray" Visibility="{Binding DetailsVisibility}">
                                        <StackPanel x:Name="MapIcon"    Background="White" >
                                            <TextBlock  Text="{Binding yourMin}" Foreground="Black"  FontWeight="SemiBold" FontSize="16" Margin="5" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords"  />
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding YourCar}" Foreground="Gray"  FontWeight="SemiBold" FontSize="12" Margin="5" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords"/>
                                            <Image Source="Your Arrow"/>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </Border>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </maps:MapItemsControl>
                </maps:MapControl>
```

Now here you just need to keep adding data to `YourData` to add more pushpin.
There are two properties added
 1. **Location**- Is of Geopoint type which will take care of position where pushpin should be placed based on latitude and longitude e.g `temp.Location = new Geopoint(new BasicGeoposition { Latitude = double.Parse(temp.Lat), Longitude = double.Parse(temp.Long) });`
 2. **Visibility**- This will be used to handle the pushpin detail visibility to be available only on taping it. eg. `temp.DetailsVisibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed;`
You will need to add these values to `YourData` for binding.

Comment: Thanks. I want to use it to show current location, for user selected location etc. As you have used MapItemsControl, will it work for single pushpin?

Comment: Yes it would work for single pushpin you just need to add a single item to `YourData`. Then you wont need the tap event to make the description visible or not as it would always be visible. 
This solution works best if you have a lot of pushpins.

Comment: Ok thanks. Will give it a try. Also, are you aware of any event which I can use for moving the pin and getting location as soon as user drops the pin at some other location?

Comment: Also make sure you handle some of the Windows Location services call as  even if `location services` is turned on after some hits it doesn't always return a value.

Comment: Is there any other way, I can achieve this without using MapItemsControl?

Comment: Without using a MapItem control you wont get your required style. You will get just windows pushpin default style. If thats what you want?

Comment: No, I want to display address also above the pin,it looks cool :-). I just need a middle section to display address, not minimum or arrow part. So I just need to use one TextBlock.

Comment: Then for that change MapItemControl StackPanel orientation to vertical and inside this shift the image down and move the border up.

Comment: this works fine, but can we create triangle shape above pin? Also, can we move the pin, as I want to add draggable pin functionality in my app?

Comment: Yes thats where my words `Custom Template` in code behind doing that is hectic. You can do one thing design this in a grid first and when you get the design that you want copy that to DataTemplate. For triangle you can use path. but usually we use an Image instead.

Comment: Ok but what about draggable pin.

Answer (score 1):

> I know how to add a map icon but not aware of adding a UI element above it.

If you need to add UIElement above the MapIcon, a possible way is to add UIElement into MapControl’s Children and set to the same coordinate( [MapControl.SetLocation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.maps.mapcontrol.setlocation.aspx)).

Here is a simple sample:

```
BasicGeoposition snPosition = new BasicGeoposition() { Latitude = 47.643, Longitude = -122.131 };
Geopoint snPoint = new Geopoint(snPosition);
Grid MyGrid = new Grid();
MyGrid.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Blue);
TextBlock text = new TextBlock();
text.Text = "Hello";
text.Width = 200;
MyGrid.Children.Add(text);
MyMapControl.Center = snPoint;
MyMapControl.ZoomLevel = 14;
// Get the address from a `Geopoint` location.
MapLocationFinderResult result = await MapLocationFinder.FindLocationsAtAsync(snPoint);

if (result.Status == MapLocationFinderStatus.Success)
{
    text.Text = "Street = " + result.Locations[0].Address.Street;
}
MyMapControl.Children.Add(MyGrid);
MapControl.SetLocation(MyGrid, snPoint);
MapControl.SetNormalizedAnchorPoint(MyGrid, new Point(0.5, 0.5));
```

Screenshot(gif):

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Also, when I add a valid MapServiceToken, the warning is always displayed. Is it that I have not created store package or something else?